# Incrementing Classes and IDs When Dynamically Adding Items to a List

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that has multiple lists of items. The user needs to be able to add more items to each list, and also add more lists to the form. My problem is that I need each input "name" and list "id" to be different.

Here is what I have:

HTML:

```
<div class="form">
    <h4>
    List 1
    </h4>
    <ul id="list">
      <li>Item 1 <input></li>
    </ul>
    <button id="addItem">
      Add Item
    </button>

  </div>

    <button id="addList">
      Add List
    </button>  
</body>
```

JQuery:

```
//add List Item
itemNumber = 2;

$("#addItem").click(function(){

newItem = "<li>Item "+ itemNumber +" <input></li>";

     $('#list').append(newItem);

     itemNumber = itemNumber + 1;
})



//add another list
listNumber = 2;

$("#addList").click(function(){

newList = "<h4>List "+ listNumber +"</h4> <ul id='list'> <li>Item 1</li> </ul> <button id='addItem'>Add Item</button>";

     $('.form').append(newList);

     listNumber = listNumber + 1;    
})
```

Currently the code will not add more items once you have added another list to the form.

[Here is a JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt8azzux/1/)

What can I do to give unique names and ids to the lists and the inputs?

*Note: I realize the HTML is not an actual form. It was easier this way for JSFiddle.

Comment: Why you need that each input has his own name and id? If you are going to add some feature like delete item you can get the closest input element to the delete button

Comment: I need to organize the inputs coherently in an object to store and post and get from the server.

Comment: @user138172 Did my answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create a list of lists.

I think it would be best to use an array so you can map the index of the list to the count of items in that list. Then you have two operations:

1. Add a list - add to the array
2. Add an item to a list - use index of list, increment the count

This means index 0 is List 1. And at index 0, you have a count of the number of items.

```js
var lists = []; // array maps index list to item count

function getNextItem(index) {
  return `<li>Item ${++lists[index]} <input /></li>`;
}

function getNextList() {
  lists.push(0);
  var index = lists.length - 1;
  return `<h4>List ${lists.length}</h4>
  <ul class="list">
    ${getNextItem(index)}
  </ul>
  <button class="addItem" data-index=${index}>Add Item</button>`;
}

$(document).on('click', '.addItem', function() {
  var index = $(this).data('index');
  var html = getNextItem(index);
  $(this).prev('.list').append(html);
})

$(document).on('click', '.addList', function() {
  var html = getNextList();
  $('.form').append(html);
});

// Initialize the first item
$('.addList').trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form"></div>
<button class="addList">Add List</button>
```

I also triggered a click to initialize the first list so the code is DRY.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following function

```
$("#addItem").click(function(){
    newItem = "<li>Item "+ itemNumber +" <input></li>";

    $('#list').append(newItem);
    itemNumber = itemNumber + 1;
});
```

with this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#addItem', function() {
    var newItem = "<li>Item "+ itemNumber +" <input></li>";

    $(this).prev().append(newItem);
    itemNumber = itemNumber + 1;
});
```

This will monitor any new item added to the document later with addItem ID. When you do this, then you'll notice that the "Add List" button starts to work as well as the Add Item. This is because I do not get the list by its ID, I find the list using its position in the DOM.

BTW, to set the name of the input, you can use the jQuery's attr utility function like this:

```
$('#myInput').attr('name', 'my_desired_name');
```

Or you can simply modify the string where you are constructing the input:

```
var newItem = "<li>Item "+ itemNumber +" <input name='" + desiredName + "'></li>";
```

Comment: Thanks Mehdi. But did you notice that the list item number increments by 1 whenever you click #addItem? The itemNumber does not stay sequential for each individual list.

Comment: That's because you are using a global variable to track the ID. You can simply use the number of items in the list to track individual items. Let me modify your JSFiddle...